# How to make git use an updated file retrospectively inside git tree

Tags: git, automated-tests, git-rebase

I have the following situation:  sometime down the tree I have created a test file that worked then.  At some point in the tree, the test broke but I didn't catch it.  I want to go to that place, and fix that test file, and then going forward be able to retest the subsequent commits using that new test file (using git bisect or otherwise, for example).  How can I do that?

```
* tuvw1 (master)
|
* oprs2
|
* xyzw3 - testfile broke here and needs to be updated hereon, onwards
|
* mnop4
|
* abcd5 - test file  first added
```

In my mind ideal answer is to be able to seamlessly incorporate the fixed test file into commits #3, #2, #1 so that I can use tools like `git bisect`.

But I will accept any reasonable answer that will allow me to test my branches from #3 onwards to master with the new test, even if a bit manually to find a new breaking point (because there is some point between commits 3 and 1 where my test breaks again).  With just 3 commits like in my example, this may be non-issue, but my actual number is more like 20 commits between broken test commit and master commit.

**Possible Solution**

I think the "ideal" answer is to simply make the new commit on top of the master, fixing my file.  Then, use `git rebase` on my commit #3 and then simply reorder commits that way I want.  The problem is then of course that I will rewrite that part of the tree, and my existing tags will be on the old tree, and not the new tree.  I will need to recreate those tags.  Also, when I `push --force` the new tree to origin, it will mess up the git tree for other developers.  It is fixable with some planning and communication, of course, but most likely it is not a great solution because of these mentioned issues.

In other words, I may just need to test manually, or test with my local tree if I need to catch various test errors.  If there is a better way to do this other than manually then that is the answer I want to know

Comment: If you really need all commits between the current breakage and the head of the branch to be fixed, then a new commit plus a `git rebase -i` to reorder the fix down is probably the easiest way to accomplish this. It does rewrite history, so you'll have to decide if that's actually required and worth the additional headache. Another possibility would be to branch from the last known good spot, fix the file, and then merge back in, or just simply put a new commit at the head - either of those, though, would not fix the in-between commits...

Comment: well what I did now is went back to commit 3, made changes to test file, then manually did my own "git bisect" type testing with the fixed test file changes in the local unstaged git space, while using `git checkout` for commits between 3 and 1.  Then I plan to add the fixed test file commit on top of master and move on with my life :)  so problem solved for me for now...

Answer (score 1):

1. It is too late to `rebase`, and that's ok. You can't always have have bug-free code in your tree, and hopefully you'll do better next time. So, you will have commits such as "Fix test cases" exactly as when you fix code.
2. That being said, you can still rebase your code on *another* branch, use `git-bisect` to automate things, etc. and eventually have a better, cleaner tree. You should not update your tags or `push --force` this branch, though. This branch is great for documentating how you solved your test issues.
3. Finally, your main branch might as-well merge this temporary branch in-order to bring all fixes to the actual branch. For example:

   ```
    ---o---A--B--C--D-------------------o--(master)
        \                              /
         \---A'--X--B'--Y--C'--(fix)--/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
git config filter.pin-content.clean 'git show HEAD:%f 2>&- || cat'
git config filter.pin-content.smudge 'cat %f 2>&- || cat' 
echo 'your/patterns filter=pin-content' >> .git/info/attributes
```

and the content won't change (`git add` runs the "clean" filter, this one ignores the worktree in favor of already-committed content; `git checkout` runs the "smudge" filter, this one ignores the committed content in favor of whatever's already in the worktree).